# nvd3 multibar chart with stacked option the bars are not appearing properly

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to use nvD3 multi bar chart for string type data representation on x-ticks.  The Group bar chart is appearing properly. However the stacked bar chart is not appearing correctly. Instead appearing one Bar on the Top of other they are getting mixed up (for Example GROUND in my plunker). Can any one help me where is the mistake?

Please find my plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywqt80KZJSBKpttabAMP?p=preview.)

My data is as follows :

```
[{
    "values" : [["2 Day", 103.89], ["NextDay", 107.41], ["Ground", 428.75]],
    "key" : "FedEx"
}, {
    "values" : [["Ground", 117.8], ["NextDay", 0], ["2 Day", 0]],
    "key" : "UPS"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequnce in which values for key `FedEx` and `UPS` has to be the same as in category `2 day, NextDay & Ground`

Like this when you pass into the chart :

```
$scope.data = [{
    "values" : [["2 Day", 103.89], ["NextDay", 107.41], ["Ground", 428.75]],
    "key" : "FedEx"
}, {
    "values" : [["2 Day", 0], ["NextDay", 0], ["Ground", 117.8]],
    "key" : "UPS"
}]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Shabeer90, but is there anyway to sort my json array to order in this fashion? I mean if I give a json array in any order, after applying some function or some thing it should return the json array in a properly ordered format as you have given.

Comment: Sorting either in java or javascript is also fine.

Comment: Thanks Shabeer, it solved the problem. In addition I have got the solution resolve this sorting issue in Angularjs,  which I am posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following sorting hast to be applied to the data model in order to resolve the appearance issue.

```
function strcmp(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
}

function natcmp(a, b) {
    var x = [], y = [];

    a[0].replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { x.push([$1 || 0, $2]) })
    b[0].replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { y.push([$1 || 0, $2]) })

    while(x.length && y.length) {
        var xx = x.shift();
        var yy = y.shift();
        var nn = (yy[0]-xx[0]) || strcmp(yy[1],xx[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }

    if(x.length) return -1;
    if(y.length) return +1;

    return 0;
}


$scope.data = $scope.data.map(function(d){ d.values = d.values.sort(natcmp); return d; });
```

Ref : [sorting json arrays in json array using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009303/sorting-json-arrays-in-json-array-using-angular-js)